# what this datetime is used for in DB query

Tags: mysql, sql

I acme across a db query

@retVal = (DATEDIFF(s, '19700101', GETUTCDATE()) - dateTime)

what this datetime used for ?? n what this query returns

Comment: Which bit are you struggling with? Both DATEDIFF and GETUTCDATE are straightforward functions if you look them up.  It would seem more likely that you'd want to know *why* this was being called, rather than how the math works out.  The answer to "why" cannot be answered without more context.

Answer (score 1):

If I've right understood your question, the number **19700101** is so-called [Unix Time Stamp](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php)

Converted it points to Mon, 17 Aug 1970 00:15:01 GMT: http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm

> The unix time stamp is a way to track time as a running total of
>   seconds. This count starts at the Unix Epoch on January 1st, 1970 at
>   UTC. Therefore, the unix time stamp is merely the number of seconds
>   between a particular date and the Unix Epoch. It should also be
>   pointed out (thanks to the comments from visitors to this site) that
>   this point in time technically does not change no matter where you are
>   located on the globe. This is very useful to computer systems for
>   tracking and sorting dated information in dynamic and distributed
>   applications both online and client side.